# Не могу понять ошибку "Uncaught ReferenceError: var is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Обновляю данные вывожу их в лог все ок получаю обновленные данные, но когда на деле их вставляю, то выдает:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: znak is not defined

а вот собственно код

```
 znac=setInterval(function (){
          znak= parseFloat($('td').eq(2).html());
    },1000);
    znac=setInterval(function (){
          lng0= parseFloat($('td').eq(2).html());
    },1000);

  myLatLng ={lat:znak,lng:lng0};
  var cntrik = {lat:40.394508, lng:49.7148758};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: cntrik
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map:map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });

  var intervalId=setInterval(function (){
      marker.setMap(null);
      console.log('udalen');
      marker.setMap(map);
      console.log('zamenen');
      console.log(znak);
      },5000);


}
```

Comment: znak= parseFloat($('td').eq(2).html()); нет пробела после znak

Comment: Я бы предложил не мучить яваскрипт, а использовать метод setPosition.

Comment: У вас две разных переменных - `znac` и `znak` ?

Comment: вреестре есть отличие)

Comment: @Grundy   нет)))))я не сдамся пока не закончу))))))))))

Comment: Латинский транслит в коде это конечно та еще глазная боль

Comment: @SLy_huh, дело привычки

Comment: @elik, откатил к исходной версии кода, иначе все ответы теряют смысл. _не стоит менять тело вопроса перенося в него код из ответов_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Основная проблема: вы не где не объявили переменную `znak`;
2) Зачем создавать два одинаковых интервала с одним и тем же промежутком времени? Если можно все значения в один запихнуть

```
var znak = parseFloat($('td').eq(2).html()) || 0,
    lng0 = znak;
var znac = setInterval(function (){
   znak = lng0 = parseFloat($('td').eq(2).html());
},1000);

myLatLng = {lat: znak, lng: lng0};
   var cntrik = {lat:40.394508, lng:49.7148758};
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: cntrik
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatLng,
   map:map,
   itle: 'Hello World!'
});

var intervalId = setInterval(function (){
   marker.setMap(null);
   console.log('udalen');
   marker.setMap(map);
   console.log('zamenen');
   console.log(znak);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51862/discussion-on-answer-by-yuri-----uncaught-referenceerror-var).

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы было возможно получить значение переменной, она **должна** быть объявлена.

В данном коде, идет попытка получения значения переменной `znak` до того, как идет ее неявное объявление с помощью присваивания в функциях таймера.

Аналогично и с `lng0`.

---

Присвоив переменной *znac* результат второго `setInterval` теряется ссылка на первый таймер и его теперь невозможно остановить. Вероятно стоит перенести это все в один таймер.

Comment: так а почему в console.log все работает

Comment: можно пример я не совсем вас понел но на примере пойму думаю ,хотя сомневаюсь что дело тут в ссылках .ведь консоль все выводит

Comment: не стоит менять тело вопроса перенося в него код из ответов. Сейчас в нем нет ни одного console.log

Comment: @elik, пример у меня в ответе. Посмотрите